# DAO interface/implementation split hierarchy and conventions

Tags: java, dao

In attempting to implement a base generic CRUD DAO, I have run into what seems a bit of an antipattern

GenericDao

```
public interface GenericDao<T, PK extends Serializable> {

  T findOne(final PK id);

  List<T> findAll();

  PK create(final T entity);

  void update(final T entity);

  void delete(final T entity);

  void deleteById(final PK id);

}
```

GenericDaoHibernateImpl

```
public abstract class GenericDaoHibernateImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements    GenericDao<T, PK> {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  private Class<T> clazz;

  public GenericDaoHibernateImpl(Class<T> clazzToSet) {
      this.clazz = clazzToSet;
  }

  protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  @Override
  public T findOne(PK id) {
    return (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> findAll() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
  }

  @Override
  public PK create(T entity) {
    return (PK) getCurrentSession().save(entity);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(T entity) {
    getCurrentSession().update(entity);
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(T entity) {
    getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
  }

  @Override
  public void deleteById(PK id) {
    final T entity = findOne(id);
    delete(entity);
  }
}
```

CustomerDao

```
public interface CustomerDao extends GenericDao<Customer, Long> {

  public Customer findByUsername(String username);

}
```

CustomerDaoHibernateImpl

```
public class CustomerDaoHibernateImpl extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Customer, Long> implements CustomerDao {

  public CustomerDaoHibernateImpl() {
    super(Customer.class);
  }

  public Customer findByUsername(String username);
    Criteria criteria =  getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
    return criteria.list();
  }

}
```

The issue I am refering to, is that in our domain specific DAO implementations, it is like we are satisfying/implementing GenericDao twice. Once in GenericDaoHibernateImpl, and then again in our domain DAO interface, ie CustomerDao. Here we must specify in the declaration, to use Customer and Long.
We then implement CustomerDaoHibernateImpl, and again we must declare Customer and Long.

Am I doing something wrong, because it just doesnt seem like the correct way to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: This is one of the reasons I don't believe in defining DAO classes using interfaces. One way to simplify your model is to remove the relationship between your CustomerDAO and GenericDAO interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never saw it as an anti-pattern for the interface and abstract class to extend/implement a common ancestor.  To me, the customer interface says it requires all operations defined in generic dao. The abstract class happens to say that it implements the generic dao. Then when you get to your customer dao impl you indicate you implement the customer interface and then have chosen to fulfill that by extending the abstract class. This allows the abstract class and the customer interface to grow or change separately if either ever wanted to not extend/implement the generic dao but the other did. Hope that makes sense

UPDATE: I see I didn't exactly answer your generics question on havIng to redundantly specify  but hope my answer gives some credibility towards the interface and abstract class having same ancestor interface

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html